# Alternate command for passenger start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I have changed my `Apache2` port from `80` to `3001`

now when i start my rails app i use

`rvmsudo rails server -p 80`

but I want to run my rails app in passenger `nginx` that I have already installed. i tried the following but not working

```
1. rvmsudo passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 80 -e development
2. rvmsudo passenger start -p 80
3. sudo passenger start -e development -p 80
```

So please let me know what the exact thing i have to do to run my app on port 80 using passenger Thnaks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Phusion Passenger's [Nginx integration mode](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html). The `passenger` command only gives you access to the Standalone mode. For more information about the differences between the Nginx integration mode and the Standalone mode, see http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html.

Comment: Not helpful i already read this! as i mentioned that i have installed passenger nginx

Comment: Then how come you are using the `passenger` command? The `passenger` command is totally unrelated to the Nginx integration mode.

Comment: i have mentioned in my querry the commands i used for passenger view the last 3 lines.

Comment: Exactly, but my point is that, if you want to use the Nginx integration mode, you are *not* supposed to use the `passenger` command.